# Carousel/slideshow doesn't work with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I'm having a problem with my code; I'm trying to create a slideshow with a number of elements defined by the for loop.

The elements present in the slideshow have title and image; I notice that I always get the last element and if I click on the arrows I cannot change the image.

`url` gives me the set of elements from which I then execute the for loop; while `url1` gives me the single element with title and image by id.

Can anyone kindly explain to me how to do this?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

var outerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://wjko5u6312.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles";

outerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var innerXmlhttp;

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var allart = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var container = document.getElementById("slideshow") 
    
    for (var i = 0, len = allart.Items.length; i < len; i++) {
      id = allart.Items[i].id
      var url1 = "https://wjko5u6312.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles/" + id;
      innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      innerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

          let div = document.createElement("div");
          let divdot = document.createElement("div");
          let img1 = document.createElement("img");
          let title1 = document.createElement("p");
          div.id = "img_fade";
          divdot.id = "dot";
          title1.id = "title1";
          img1.id = "img1";
          document.getElementById("title1").innerHTML = myArr.Item.title;
          document.getElementById("img1").src = myArr.Item.image;
        }
      };
      innerXmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
      innerXmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
};

outerXmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
outerXmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="id"></p>

  <div class="slideshow-container" id="slideshow">
    <div class="img fade" id="img_fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img id="img1" src onerror="this.onerror=null;" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text" id="title1"></div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center" id="dot">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the AJAX do? The slider looks alot like bxSlider.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually run your code, but upon a quick glance, it appears your `showSlides()` function accepts an index, `n`, but other than checking for limits (1 and the length of the `slides` array), you never actually use this parameter to update the value of `slideIndex` -- which is the only variable ever actually sent to this function.

In other words, `slideIndex` never actually changes, and the images shown are determined by `slideIndex`, rather than `n`. As you're using the global variable to keep track of where you are in the slideshow, you will at least need to set `slideIndex` to the value of the local variable `n` within `showSlides` (preferably before checking its limits in this case).

Comment: so what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: I've edited the answer, but you need to change the value of `slideIndex` to the value of `n` somewhere in your `showSlides()` function. Otherwise, you'll always be sending the same number to the function, no matter how many times you press next/back.